# Nested cells matlab

Tags: matlab, cells

I have a 73 x 1 cell, each of those cells contains a 16 x 1 cell and each of those cells is an image. Is there an easy way I can convert this into one big array of cells containing only the images? Many thanks.

[image]

Comment: What is the shape of your final big cell array?

Comment: @dan I've added a picture. That's the 73 x 1 cell array I have at the moment. Basically I'd like to expand that into either a 73 x 16 array (by expanding out out 16 x 1 array) or just one big row/column of every cell so I can access images easily.

Comment: Have you looked at [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html)?

Comment: @eigenchris unfortunatley seems to turn the 16 x 1 arrays into one big matrix which isn't ideal - I'd like to keep the images separate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `C` is your cell, use `B = [C{:}]` to create a 16×73 cell `B` with every column one of your original 16×1 cell elements. This works, because `C{:}` accesses every element in cell `C` and the brackets (`[ ]`) group all these elements into one array again. This is possible, because every element in `C` is of the same type and size.

Use `B = B(:)` to get a 1168×1 cell (73*16=1168), if you want. Either way, `B{n}` accesses the `n`-th image.