# Converting cells within cells to single cells

Tags: matlab, cells

I have a 1X100 cell which contains exclusivly 1X24 cells. I need to extract these 100 cells and join them together to form a 100X24 cell, how can this be done?

I have been playing around with the 'cellfun' function and also using for loops to try an perform the operations required but without success. I understand I could just join these cells one by one but would prefer a more efficient approach. Any help would be appreciated.

The cell is generated from raw data using the following:

```
for i = 1:100
   band{i} = prctile(e-data,i);
end
```

where e_data is a 62X24 double

Comment: I'd say: dont generate the data as a cell! you can just do the same by doing `band(i)=...` or `band(i,:)=...`

Comment: @AnderBiguri's comment is, of course, the correct answer. However, sometimes that isn't possible (such as the output from `regexp` with the `tokens` flag). In which case, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31588250/nested-cells-matlab?rq=1) should help.

Comment: Thank you, I had spent so long looking at it I had become snow blind.

Answer (score 3):

The second input to `prctile` can be an [*array of percentages*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prctile.html#inputarg_p) so your code can be replaced with

```
band = prctile(e - data, 1:100).';
```

This will create a 100 x 24 numeric array which is going to be more performant than a cell array.

In general though, if you need to concatenate the contents of multiple cells together, you can use `{:}` indexing to yield a [comma separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) which can then be passed to `cat`

```
result = cat(1, band{:});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your purpose correctly, you need to use `iscell()` and retrieve what you want subsequently:

```
R=cellfun(@iscell, YourCell);
Demanded_Cell=YourCell(R);
```